# Why does my content dissappear behind my header in compatibility mode?

Tags: html, css, ie8-compatibility-mode

When running the following layout in compatibility mode, the content disappears behind the fixed header. Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

See the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tAPvu/2/) and switch between compatibility mode in IE. The Layout works fine in chrome and IE9 when not in compatibility mode.

Header css is basically:

```
#headerContainer
{
    position: fixed;    
    top:0px;   
    z-index:999;
    background:green;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And content css is:

```
#container{
overflow:hidden;
padding-left:480px; /* The width of the rail */
margin-top: 135px;
background: red;
}
```

Its a fixed-fluid layout (left rail is fixed) with a fixed header. When scrolling down I want the content of the page to disappear below the header.

Comment: So you want it to go over the header?

Comment: Nope I want the header to remain fixed and the content to disappear below it when scrolling - that's how it behaves when compatibility mode is off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix for IE compatibility mode:

```
#container{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-left:480px; /* The width of the rail */
    margin-top: 135px;
    background: red;
    *position:relative;
    *top:135px;
}
```

I've used CSS hack (with `*`) for IE7.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/phPAN/